# When would a moderator want to edit the top-of-page text at /election?

Tags: discussion, moderation, election

Anime.SE has just entered [the nomination phase of its first election cycle](https://anime.stackexchange.com/election/). As an appointed beta moderator, I notice that I have the ability to edit the blurb of text that tells users how elections work ("On Stack Exchange, we believe the core moderators should come *from* the community...").

When would a moderator want to edit that blurb? Is it even appropriate to do so? I would think we'd want this blurb to be standard across all sites. Can any other moderators comment on situations in which they've found a need to edit that blurb?

Answer (score 2):

This ability is almost certainly intended to be only used by Stack Exchange employees, it might not even work for moderators if they actually tried to submit changes. That it looks like you can edit it (or maybe even actually edit it) is probably just a bug.

There are a few reasons to change this text, e.g. adding a link to the candidate responses to the collected questions. I think the additional requirements for nomination like certain badges that are present on some sites are also mentioned in that text.

There are some valid reasons to edit this text, but not for moderators, only for Stack Exchange employees.

Comment: Just checked; I _can_ actually make edits to the blurb